# "optimization" tag

Tags: discussion, tags

The [optimization](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization) tag has no definition and was added to 31 questions.

It’s not clear to me what it should/could represent, and if it makes sense on all of the questions that currently have it. Many seem to be about programming, but not all.

Do we need this tag? If yes, what should be its definition?

Comment: Looks like splitting it up to e.g. `code-optimization` and `system-optimization` (just two examples) would make them more useful indeed. But I'm afraid that could mean at least 5 different tags, some with 5 questions or less; would those still be useful then?

Comment: I'd say it would be useful, @Izzy. Having the tags around would be good for future askers.

Comment: @Undo I'm not opposed to it – I was just hoping for more feedback to help a decision (which I don't want to make alone ;) Btw, one of those upvotes is mine ;)